# Show that $n!+1$ has a prime factor $\;>n$; showthat there are infinitely many primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I don't know how to prove this and it's really bugging me. Thanks to anybody that can help!

Let $n$ be any natural number. Prove that $n! + 1$ contains a prime factor greater than $n$ and use that to prove that there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Posting your question as the title seems to have cutoff part of it.

Comment: Thank you for notifying me of my mistake, I have corrected it and added the whole question to the body. :D

Comment: My copy paste was incorrect. My mistake. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

For any $a \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $a$ and $a+1$ are *relatively prime*, that is, $\gcd(a,a+1) = 1$, or in other words $d \mid a$ and $d \mid a+1$ implies $d = 1$.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I still don't quite understand how to use this hint. :(

Comment: @Michael If $n!+1$ itself is a prime, then it is done. If not, it has a prime factor $p$, if $p\le n$, then $p|n!+1$, but we know $p|n!$, that means $p|1$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: *Any* prime factor of $n!+1$ is greater than $n$.